# Como recortar uma imagem ao centro ao fazer o upload da mesma

Tags: php, imagem, upload

No projeto aqui eu quero exibir as imagens em uma div quadrada de dimensão dinâmica onde seu tamanho máximo é 240 x 240.

supondo que um usuário faça o upload de uma imagem com dimensão retangular (ex: 500 x 280), essa mesma div fica "desfigurada" já que o height dela é auto, assim a altura fica proporcional a largura. E meu objetivo e deixar todas as div com formato quadrado.

Sendo assim eu preciso garantir que todas as imagens que serão exibas possuam dimensoes quadradas, ou seja, 200x200, 300x300, ou qualquer outro tamanho desde que seja quadrada.

Ao meu ver uma forma fácil de se fazer isso é recortando ao imagem na hora do upload. E de preferencia o recorte tem que ser no centro da imagem. EX:

[image: Imagem usada no upload, sem o recorte]

[image: Imagem usada no upload com o recorte]

Como pode-se ver, a imagem foi recortada ao centro, e agora ela possui Altura e Largura identica.

Comment: Não sei se esse automático é o melhor... Nem todas as imagens tem o foco no centro.

Comment: Procurei na internet e to utilizando o jcrop, assim quando faz o upload o usuário pode escolher qual ponto da imagem ele desejar exibir. Dessa forma resolvo os dois problemas. Um sobre o a imagem se de tamanho diverso e o outro sobre o foco da imagem, assim o próprio usuário decidi qual parte da imagem é a melhor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bom galera, a pergunta era sobre como recortar uma imagem ao centro ao fazer o upload da mesma. Pesquisei na internet e acabei mudando de ideia e usando o JCROP, porém a pergunta em em si só não tinha sido respondida, procurei então sobre o assunto na internet e acabei achando o um script que solucionava a minha pergunta. O script não é meu, porém fiz um pouco pequenas edições para se adaptar melhor ao meu objetivo inicial.

Eis o script:

```
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="img" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" name="cadastrar" />
  </form>


  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])){ 
  $img  = $_FILES['img'];
  $name =$img['name'];
  $tmp  =$img['tmp_name'];
  $ext  =end(explode('.',$name));

  $pasta        ='NOMEDAPASTA/'; //Pasta onde a imagem será salva

  $permiti  =array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
  $name = uniqid().'.'.$ext; $uid = uniqid();

  $upload   = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $pasta.'/'.$name);}; //Faz o upload da imagem para o servidor

  if($upload){
  function resize_crop_image($max_width, $max_height, $source_file, $dst_dir, $quality = 60){
  $imgsize = getimagesize($source_file);
  $width = $imgsize[0];
  $height = $imgsize[1];
  $mime = $imgsize['mime'];
  //resize and crop image by center
  switch($mime){
  case 'image/gif':
  $image_create = "imagecreatefromgif";
  $image = "imagegif";
  break;
  //resize and crop image by center
  case 'image/png':
  $image_create = "imagecreatefrompng";
  $image = "imagepng";
  $quality = 6;
  break;
  //resize and crop image by center
  case 'image/jpeg':
  $image_create = "imagecreatefromjpeg";
  $image = "imagejpeg";
  $quality = 60;
  break;
  default:
  return false;
  break;
  }
  $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($max_width, $max_height);
  $src_img = $image_create($source_file);
  $width_new = $height * $max_width / $max_height;
  $height_new = $width * $max_height / $max_width;
  if($width_new > $width){
  $h_point = (($height - $height_new) / 2);
  imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, $h_point, $max_width, $max_height, $width, $height_new);
  }else{
  $w_point = (($width - $width_new) / 2);
  imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $w_point, 0, $max_width, $max_height, $width_new, $height);
  }
  $image($dst_img, $dst_dir, $quality);
  if($dst_img)imagedestroy($dst_img);
  if($src_img)imagedestroy($src_img);
  }

  //Tamanho da Imagem final
  resize_crop_image(300, 300, $pasta.'/'.$name, $pasta.'/'.$name);}


  ?>
```

Answer (score 8):

Baixe o pacote [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Download.html) e faça duas páginas assim:

***Página Inicial: (crop.php)***

```cs
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Arquivo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.12/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript"> 
    $(function(){ 
        $('#ImagemCrop').Jcrop({
            aspectRatio: 1,
            onSelect: UpdateCrop,
            setSelect: [0, 0, 200, 200],
        });

    }); 
    function UpdateCrop(c)
    {
        $('#x').val(c.x);
        $('#y').val(c.y);
        $('#w').val(c.w);
        $('#h').val(c.h);
        $("#altura").html("Altura:" + c.h);
        $("#largura").html("Largura:" + c.w);
    };  
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="altura">Altura:</div>
    <div id="largura">Largura:</div>
    <form action="recorte.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
        <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
        <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
        <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
        <input type="hidden" id="imagem" name="imagem" value="img/1.jpg" />
        <input type="submit" value="Recortar Imagem" />
    </form>
    <img src="img/1.jpg" id="ImagemCrop" />
</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

***Página que recebe os dados para o recorte: (recorte.php)***

```cs
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['imagem']) && 
        isset($_POST['x']) && 
        isset($_POST['y']) && 
        isset($_POST['w']) && 
        isset($_POST['h']))
    {
        $targ_w = $_POST['w'];
        $targ_h = $_POST['h'];
        $jpeg_quality = 90;

        $src = $_POST['imagem'];
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
        $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

        imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
        $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);    
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer isso com o corte no lodo do servidor, eu utilizo [imagine](http://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) tem uma abordagem OO muito interessante para manipulação de imagens.

### Instalação

Adicione em seu arquivo composer.json a seguinte dependência:

```js
"require": {
    "imagine/imagine": "dev-master"
},
```

### Exemplo de uso

```php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

$imagine = new Imagine\Gd\Imagine();

$size = new Imagine\Image\Box(200, 200);

$mode = Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_OUTBOUND;

$imagine->open($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])
        ->thumbnail($size, $mode)
        ->save(__DIR__ . '/upload/' . $_FILES['file']['name'])
;
```